# An SVN error (200 OK) when checking out from my online repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to set up my first repository on my host and am getting this error when I use [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) to checkout the project:

> Error: OPTIONS of `http://mywebsite.example/svn/myproject`: 200 OK (`http://mywebsite.example`)

Here is what I did:

1. SSH into my host and head to `/home/myaccnt` and 'svnadmin create svn'
2. Create my project repository: 'svn mkdir svn/myproject'
3. Add files to the repository: cd `/home/myaccnt/.../myproject` (which has /tags, /branch, /trunk); 'svn import file:///home/myaccnt/svn/myproject'  (the big old list of files being added is seen at this point.) 
   At this point I think that I've setup my repository and imported my project into the repository. So, I'm ready to checkout using TortoiseSVN on my Windows box. So:
4. In the folder I'd like to checkout to, I right click and *SVN Checkout*, and then make sure my URL is: `http://mywebsite.example/svn/myproject`

Result?

> Error: OPTIONS of `http://mywebsite.example/svn/myproject`: 200 OK (`http://mywebsite.example`)

Anyone have any thoughts for me? I'm likely missing something fundamental with the structure of my repository or htaccess... or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, this is more a restriction issue by my host, and I am working with them to resolve it.

Thanks, 1800.

BTW, the answer here was that my host, A2 Web Hosting, requires that SVN be handled via SSH using a public_key and configuring, in my case, TortoiseSVN to do the job. It was sort of funky for someone who has just a little experience setting up keys, but it was pretty satisfying once it was done!

You can find information about SVN on the A2 host in their support wiki.

Answer (score 82):

I had to dig into this issue too and found the following pages which lead me to the solution:
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.subversion.devel/117844
(See especially the [link to "Julian's patch"](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2010-01/0211.shtml).)

There is stated that the "OPTIONS of `<url>`: 200 (`<url>`) OK" error is quite misleading and often just means that the repository URL is wrong.

Comment: Yea. In most cases it's a wrong url. I just had it again also, but I always forget the cause of it.

Comment: We see this error from time to time with our customers at ProjectLocker as well, and it's always an incorrect URL.  Please accept the above answer.

Comment: It's rare to see an answer with 66 upvotes lose to one with 2.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken (*"ArchivedAt Nothing found - bye"*).

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem with a simple "svn list" command.

To extend Vitor Mateus' answer regarding slashes: While setting up my own repository using Apache on an in-house server, my original `Location` tag in the Apache 2 configuration file looked like:

```
<Location "/svn/repo_address/">
    ...
</Location>
```

Where there was a ***trailing "/"*** after "repo_address". There should not be a slash there:

```
<Location "/svn/repo_address">
    ...
</Location>
```

Something subtle, but it makes a huge difference. Now a call to

```
svn list http://my.server.example/svn/repo_address
```

works fine. Sometimes it helps to read the manual carefully ;-)

Comment: +1 This was the only one from many others that solved my problem. Thanks million times! :)

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem. My Subversion server was on a non-standard port. So effectively my repository URL was wrong. Just something else to check...

Answer (score 3):

For me, the error was on the server side, and it was because I forgot to uncomment

```
DAV svn
```

in the configuration file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf` (on Debian).

Answer (score 2):

If you change the checkout address from `http://mywebsite.example/svn/myproject` to `svn://mywebsite.example/svn/myproject`, does it start working? If so, maybe you didn't set up the HTTP protocol for SVN access?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was definitely an authentication issue.

Normally when I attempt to checkout a new project, I am asked if I want to accept the certificate (permanently, temporary, or not at all).

I must have clicked *not at all* previously, so it wouldn't prompt me again.

Using the TortoiseSVN client I went into *Settings*, then *Saved Data* and cleared my *Authentication data* (button <kbd>Clear</kbd>).

Then when I attempted a checkout, it prompted me to accept the certificate. I did *Permanently* and all was good. It checked out all my code.

Answer (score 1):

This error is completely generic and just means it couldn't communicate with the SVN server. Use your browser to look at the URL and see what's really being served. It should be a plain black and white page that says Powered by Subversion in the footer. That should help you figure out what the problem is.

In my case the requests were not ending up at the DAV module because I'm using ProxyPass.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `/` on the end of URL. Change the checkout address from `http://mywebsite.example/svn/myproject` to `http://mywebsite.example/svn/myproject/`.

Answer (score 0):

A modification of the first response worked for me.

My repository uses SSH. The URL was given to me as https:// (for HTTPS access) and I eventually figured out that the protocol on the URL needed to be changed.

Using the command-line client:
`svn checkout svn+ssh://<hostName>/svnroot/<projectName>/`

(No key configuration was needed.)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error while connecting to an open source repository from my Ubuntu x-term.

The solution that worked was modifing `/etc/subversion/servers` file. I modified the proxy settings in the global section and now: All is well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure SVNPath is set correctly in the Apache configuration!

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for getting this error (among the many above) is having a proxy set in ~/.subversion/servers when you don't need a proxy to get to the server you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem (and a solution). I do not understand why it happens, but since some of the repository DID checkout, I tried to checkout various content independently.

I've found that only a JAR file in the root folder was not checked out and attempting to check it out caused the error. Since the file was a duplicate file of a same JAR file, which was in the "target" folder, I just deleted it from the repository via repo-browser (TortoiseSVN) and checked out the project via NetBeans again - finally it finished without the error.