# How to checout from IP? SVN

Tags: svn

I'm trying to checkout from an IP but I'm getting:

```
svn checkout http://me@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/home/usr/svn/project
svn: OPTIONS of 'htp://me@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/home/usr/svn/project': 200 OK
```

Im not sure why Im getting OPTIONS, I want to check out!
Thanks!

Comment: SVN uses an extension of the HTTP protocol (WebDAV) for communication. It seems to send a `OPTIONS` request to the server and to get an unexpected `200 OK` response—probably a configuration problem. (In this case, your question is no longer programming-related :-))

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like apache isn't configured correctly.  What happens if you browse to that URL in a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be another post like this with a resolution as well - you might see if that helps your situation.Likely related to access configuration.

[An SVN error (200 OK) when checking out from my online repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025377/an-svn-error-200-ok-when-checking-out-from-my-online-repo)