# SVN repository browser issue

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I use TortoiseSVN on WindowsXP and ran into an issue inside repository browser today.

Basically, I can browser/checkout fine at application level "https://domain/svn/app1".
However, When I try to browse at the root level of the repository "https://domain/svn/", the following error msg displays:

OPTIONS of 'https://domain/svn': 200 OK

I try to access https://domain/svn in a web browser, I can see all the applications there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means there is no actual SVN repo at this address (see [this patch](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2010-01/0211.shtml)), but rather a collection of SVN repo (that your apache is showing you in your web browser).
Note: other reasons for this message to pop up can be found in the SO question "[An SVN error (200 OK) when checking out from my online repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025377/an-svn-error-200-ok-when-checking-out-from-my-online-repo)"

The "correct" error message would be:

```
> svn checkout svn://localhost/repos 
> svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://localhost/repos' 
> svn: Can't connect to host 'localhost': Connection refused 

> $ svn checkout file://localhost/repos 
> svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file://localhost/repos' 
> svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
```