# how do I checkout svn with http authentication on mac

Tags: svn, git-svn, basic-authentication

When I do a :

```
svn co http://<url>/<repo> <local_dir>
```

on my macbook (10.6.6) I get the following message:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://<url>/<repo>': 200 OK (http://<url>)
```

without any prompt for password or anything useful happening.

`<url>` is the dev/repo machine on the network.  Usually I can do the same checkout from the dev machine but another developer is able to check it out from a different linux box and the windows developers can checkout locally using tortoise-svn without problems.

Is there something special I need to do to solve this for mac?
Extra:  really I am using git-svn but then I realized that even regular svn isn't working so I thought I would start there.  Is there anything I different I need to do to use git-svn with http authentication

Answer (score 14):

If you know that the url needs authentication, you can try if the following works.

```
svn co http://<url>/<repo> <local_dir> --username user --password password
```

Edit 1:  I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025377/an-svn-error-200-ok-when-checking-out-from-my-online-repo) SO question, which gives an explanation for `200 OK message`. So you may want to cross-check your url as well.

Comment: the username/password didn't help - reading through the other questions - thanks.