# Checking out a repository I created on a server using SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

This is my first time creating a SVN repository. I am running into problems on the client machine when I try to check out my repo files. I have no issues when I try to check things out on the machine where I created the repos; i.e. when I do: `svn co file:///repo_path/project_name/trunk`

But, when I try to access the same from a remote machine using network protocol (http://...), I get the same issue as described in [An SVN error (200 OK) when checking out from my online repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025377/an-svn-error-200-ok-when-checking-out-from-my-online-repo).

Unfortunately, that discussion did not help me since I'm sure I have the right SVN HTTP URL. I checked the conf/svnserve.conf and saw the following:

```
[general]
anon-access = read
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
realm = My First Repository
```

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: `passwd` is present and contains entries?

Comment: Yes. There is a file called conf/passwd whose entries 'code' ### This file is an example password file for svnserve.
[users]
# harry = harryssecret
# sally = sallyssecret
'code' Do i need to edit this? Please help me in configuring the repo so that i can access the project files over the network using http or svn+ssh protocol. Or please point me to the literature. I tried reading thro' the redbean guide but there is no useful examples on configuring and making the repo available over network. Thanks.

Comment: Describe what you get when you point a normal web browser to that URL. Compate that to a real http(s) URL like from [ScummVM SF.net project](https://scummvm.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/scummvm/).

Comment: You also want to [read the book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My configuration consists of three files (located in the `conf` folder):

- `authz`
- `passwd`
- `svnserve.conf`

They serve the following purpose:

`svnserve.conf`:
configures the overall access to the repo and provides the following content:

```
[general]
anon-access = none
password-db = passwd    # password database
authz-db    = authz     # authorization rules
```

`passwd`:
provides passwords for certain users:

```
harry = password
sally = password
charlie = password
```

`authz:`
authorization file for svnserve:

```
[groups]
# put harry and sally into the developers group
developers = harry,sally

# configure access for the root of the repo
[/]
# developers group has read/write access
@developers = rw
# charlie can only read
charlie = r
```

This should do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @eckes. I have just three more follow up questions. Firstly, what's the "svn checkout" command look like if i have to take into account the user-name/pass-word in the checkout command? Secondly, do i need to re-start the svn daemon after making changes to the files in the conf folder. Finally, my svn repo is created under the $HOME dir: svn/myRepos. So, my URL will be http://domain_name.com/svn/myRepos/project_name/trunk, right? Thanks a ton.

Comment: Pls ignore questions #1 and #2. I found the solution for those two looking at the help for "svn co" command. I am still unable to check out the files. I created a user/password as testuser/testuserpassword. Then i restated the svnserve daemon. Then did the following: svn co http://domain_name/path_to_repo/project_name/trunk --username testuser --password testuserpassword. I am still unable to check out files. Should i start looking at the ports and firewall, network configuration, etc? Any idea what port is the default for SVN?