# error checking out subversion repository

Tags: svn

I'm trying to checkout a working copy of subversion project, I've tried it through Netbeans, via command line and rapid Svn. I get the error

```
 Execute: Checkout
 Error: Error while performing action: The PROPFIND response contains    invalid XML (200 OK)
```

I'm using ubuntu desktop. Any ideas gratefully received. thanks

Comment: What version of SVN (client and server) & RapidSVN are you using? Are you certain that your URL, authentication & authorization are correct? Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1025377/1324345?

Comment: @alroc svn locally is 1.8.8 (don't know remote) and 0.12.1 RapidSVN.  I also get this error code prefixed as well svn: E130003: The PROPFIND response contains invalid XML (200 OK)  , my colleague with mac can svn in with the same credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you enter incorrect URL to the repository. Make sure that the URL is correct.

Comment: yeah, the client / colleague gave me the wrong url it should have been svn.dev.website and he was looking at it all the time with me, hahahah